# What are are some illustrative (non-)examples of proper morphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition, schemes, topos-theory, locales

"Proper" is an adjective used to describe a morphism of spaces—[topological spaces, schemes, locales, etc](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+morphism#definitions)—that is sufficiently nice and has some [neat properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism#Properties_and_characterizations_of_proper_morphisms). Between topological spaces a morphism is *proper* if the preimage of compact set is compact, which is a clean definition, but it doesn't give me any geometric intuition that generalizes to schemes or beyond. Similarly the definitions I've seen for a proper morphisms of schemes hasn't helped improve my intuition.

What are some flags/heuristics/features of a morphism that I should look out for to decide whether or not it's proper? What are some illustrative examples or non-examples of proper morphisms, in whatever setting, that could help build my geometric intuition here? [This answer over on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/30627/64073) helps a bit, but only a bit,

Comment: I suspect that "proper" is a term that has just been indroduced independently in different contexts with no proper consideration for the bigger picture.

Comment: @Arthur [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proper+morphism) and the [other answer to that MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/20887/64073) suggest otherwise.